# Carmichael numbers of the form $\ n^2+1\ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, carmichael-numbers

> For which positive integers $\ n\ $ is $\ N:=n^2+1\ $ a Carmichael-number ?

The smallest examples are summarized in this table (the program is currently still in progress) :

```
gp > forstep(m=2,10^9,2,n=m^2+1;if(Mod(2,n)^(n-1)==1,if(carm(n)==1,print(m,"   ",n,"   ",factor(n)))))
216   46657   [13, 1; 37, 1; 97, 1]
1560   2433601   [17, 1; 37, 1; 53, 1; 73, 1]
8208   67371265   [5, 1; 13, 1; 37, 1; 109, 1; 257, 1]
592956   351596817937   [17, 1; 37, 1; 197, 1; 433, 1; 6553, 1]
649800   422240040001   [13, 1; 37, 1; 41, 1; 73, 1; 241, 1; 1217, 1]
4321800   18677955240001   [29, 1; 61, 1; 101, 1; 197, 1; 701, 1; 757,     1]
21415680   458631349862401   [37, 1; 53, 1; 89, 1; 19009, 1; 138241, 1]
```

Is it known whether infinite many such Carmichael numbers exist ? And how can I enumerate them more efficiently ?

Comment: Cf. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A265285)

Comment: An interesting question. Answers are not as easy. A reasonable asymptotic behavior regarding the number of these up to a limit of $x$ is : $\frac {1}{5}log(x)$. So I assume the existence of infinite Carmichael numbers of the form $n^{2}+1$.
One can determine these numbers more efficiently by recognizing that $n$ is a rather smooth number. I'm working on an improved answer but don't expect proves.